# How can a local function variable be accessible in another function

Tags: javascript, local-variables

```
var objectTest=
{
    test1:  function( )
    {
       val1 = 1;
    },

    // hows accessing the 
    test2:  function( )
    {
       alert( val1 );
    }
};

objectTest.test2( );
```

Comment: are you saying that it is accessing it?

Comment: This question is not clear at all.

Comment: did you give up on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By not using the prefix `var` the variable is put in different (global) scope try instead:

```
test1: function() {
 var val1=1;
},
```

As @Pekka points out, your example (above) requires the calling of `objectTest.test1();` first (to create `val1`) otherwise you'll get an error.  If you **want** to access the variable from both places, then you should rather be using an object-property (like @patrick dw suggests) which doesn't add to the global scope

```
objectTest.test1();
objectTest.test2(); //Shows: Alert-1
alert(val1); //Shows: Alert-1
val1=2;
objectTest.test(2); //Shows: Alert-2
```

Comment: But how will this make `val1` local to `test2()`?

Comment: Pekka!  LTNS.  Is that what he's asking?

Answer (score 1):

It can't. Two functions can't run at the same time, so sharing local scope is impossible the way you show. You would have to define `val1` as a member of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you ultimately want to do. You could make it a public member of the object:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/wqr6W/

```
var objectTest=
{
    val1: 'someDefault',
    test1:  function( )
    {
       this.val1 = 1;
    },

    // hows accessing the 
    test2:  function( )
    {
       alert( this.val1 );
    }
};
objectTest.test1( );
objectTest.test2( );
```

This of course changes your original code. What you actually need to do will depend on your circumstance.

Or this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/wqr6W/1/

```
var objectTest=
{
    val1: 'someDefault',
    test1:  function( )
    {
       this.val1 = 1;
    },

    // hows accessing the 
    test2:  function( )
    {
       this.test1();
       alert( this.val1 );
    }
};
objectTest.test2( );
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer in order to more directly answer the question.

If you are actually talking about a *local* variable to a function, the simple answer is that you can *not* access it *unless* you pass a function out of the function that has the variable, which makes reference to the variable.

This is called creating a closure.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/csd3s/

```
var objectTest=
{
    test1:  function( )
    {
       var val1 = 1;
       return {getVal:function() {
           return val1;
       }};
    },

    // hows accessing the 
    test2:  function( )
    {
       alert( this.test1().getVal() );
    }
};

objectTest.test2( );
```

So inside `test2` you can call the `test1()` function, which returns an object that contains a function, which references the local variable.

That (or something similar) is what it takes to reference an otherwise non-accessible local variable in a function.